# Conditional Probability - Calculations

Tags: probability

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two events with $P(A) = \frac{2}{3}, P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(A \cap B) = \frac{2}{5}$. Calculate:
>
> $(i)$ $P(A \mid B) $ and $P(B \mid A) $
>
> $(ii)$ $P(A \cup B)$
>
> $(iii)$ $P(A^c \mid B)$
>
> (iv) $P(B^c \mid A^c)$

**My answers:**

$(i):$ $P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{\frac{2}{3}}{0.5} = \frac{4}{5}$ and with the same calculation $P(B \mid A) = \frac{3}{5}$.

$(ii):$ $P(A \cup B)= P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = \frac{23}{30}$.

$(iii):$ $P(A^c \mid B) = \frac{P(A^c \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B)-P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{1}{5}$.

$(iv):$ $P(B^c \mid A^c) = \frac{P(B^c \cap A^c)}{P(A^c)} = \frac{P(A^c \mid B^c)}{P(A^c \mid B) \cdot P(B) + P(A^c \mid B^c) \cdot P(B^c)} = \frac{\frac{14}{30} \cdot \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{7}{10}$.

Can someone please check my solutions and let me know if I made any mistakes? Thank you.

Comment: You have a typo in your work for (i) but it appears it was just a typo as you finished correctly.  $2/5$ for the numerator rather than $2/3$.  At a glance, your workings are all correct and assuming your arithmetic is correct and you made no mistakes or additional typos it looks all fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks correct (one typo aside).

I would note two things.

(iii) $\mathsf P(A^\complement\mid B)=1-\mathsf P(A\mid B)=1/5$

(iv) $\mathsf P(B^\complement\mid A^\complement)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)}{\mathsf P(A^\complement)}=\dfrac{1-\mathsf P(A\cup B)}{1-\mathsf P(A)}=7/10$

The final answers are the same, but the calculations would have been easier.